# Where to find the earliest unabridged version of the Valmiki Ramayana?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, history, valmiki, manuscripts

Where to find the earliest unabridged version (Not the abridged critical version) of the Valmiki Ramayana with Sanskrit verses?
Preferably with translations into Hindi or English and also preferably as a hard copy but online would work as well.
P.S: Not the Gita Press ones

Answer (score 4):

http://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/ Here you can read for free , difference is that this website has removed uttara kanda while gita press has included uttara kanda.

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.21755/page/n17/mode/2up
Here also Uttara Kanda has been removed

https://archive.org/details/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SanskritTextWithHindiTranslation-DpSharma10/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SktHindi-DpSharmaVol01-BalaKanda1927/page/n35/mode/2up Here hindi translation is there and uttara kanda is present too but font is not that good .

Comment: Any other options than the Gita Press ones for the hard copy?

Comment: @Zaitor7 Gita press one is highly recommended and regarded as most authentic.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Gita press 's translation is most authentic , but they don't decide whether some verses are interpolated or not . Oriental Institute of Baroda has written critical edition of Ramayana where all those verses which were not present in different manuscripts of ramayana present all over india have been removed .

Comment: @Raghav I feel a genuine reader would be able to identify the interpolated verses.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto well to identify interpolations major help comes from Vedas , because whatever goes against vedas is definitely interpolation and beauty of Vedas is that samhitas  are fully preserved . Now in case of Ramayana , problem is there are basic evidences which support both presence and absence of uttara kanda , so a common reader like me won't be able to decide . However a highly qualified Sanskrit and Vedic scholar might be able to decide whether Uttara Kanda is interpolated or not. By the way , you want me to share english translation of critical edition of valmiki ramayana ?

Comment: Well, some of the the translations of Gita Press are disputed. That is why was looking for something other than Gita Press.

Comment: @Zaitor7 are those links useful ?

Comment: Yes @RaghavGoyal, they are useful but I would have preferred a hard copy version so was looking for something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

Srimad Valmiki Ramayana Gita Press, in Sanskrit- English, found on archive.org:
https://archive.org/details/valmiki-ramayana-gita-press-english/page/n1/mode/1up

Or, it can be downloaded here:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/og9i8et1hq3taa6/Valmiki_Ramayana_Gita_Press_English.pdf/file